# Windows Service will not start

Tags: c#, service, .net

Not sure what the problem is. I looked online to try to ascertain why my service will not start, i am getting a 1053 error on my win 8. I tried on a win 7 machine and got the same error but no code. If the below code code looks familiar it's a mod of 
: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18521/How-to-implement-a-simple-filewatcher-Windows-serv. I got this example from Microsoft : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx to work though(A console app). Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="WatchPath" value="C:\\testbin\\" />
</appSettings>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceProcess;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.IO;

    namespace FileWatcher
    {
        public partial class FileWatcherService : ServiceBase
        {
            private StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt");

            public FileWatcherService()
            {
              InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {
              FileWatcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPath"];
              //StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt");
            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
            }


    }

    using System;
    namespace FileWatcher
    {
               partial class FileWatcherService
               {
               /// <summary> 
               /// Required designer variable.
               /// </summary>
               /// 
               // log1 = new logClassogClass();

               private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

               /// <summary>
               /// Clean up any resources being used.
               /// </summary>

               protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
               {
                    if (disposing && (components != null))
                    {
                         components.Dispose();
                    }
                    base.Dispose(disposing);
               }

        #region Component Designer generated code

        /// <summary> 
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify 
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.FileWatcher = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FileWatcher)).BeginInit();
            // 
            // FileWatcher
            // 
            this.FileWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            this.FileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
            this.FileWatcher.Changed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);
            this.FileWatcher.Created += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);
            this.FileWatcher.Deleted += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);
            this.FileWatcher.Filter = "*.*";
            //this.FileWatcher.Renamed += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);
            //this.FileWatcher.Changed = FileWatcher_Changed;
            // 
            // FileWatcherService
            // 
            //FileWatcher.Changed = += new System.IO.FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Changed);
            this.ServiceName = "FileWatcherService";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.FileWatcher)).EndInit();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.IO.FileSystemWatcher FileWatcher;

        /* DEFINE WATCHER EVENTS... */
        /// <summary>
        /// Event occurs when the contents of a File or Directory are changed
        /// </summary>

        protected  void FileWatcher_Changed(object sender,
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //code here for newly changed file or directory
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event occurs when the a File or Directory is created
        /// </summary>
        private void FileWatcher_Created(object sender,
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //code here for newly created file or directory
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File created");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Event occurs when the a File or Directory is deleted
        /// </summary>
        private void FileWatcher_Deleted(object sender,
                        System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //code here for newly deleted file or directory
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File deleted");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Event occurs when the a File or Directory is renamed
        /// </summary>
        private void FileWatcher_Renamed(object sender,
                        System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            //code here for newly renamed file or directory
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File edited");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
    }


}


}
```

Comment: The event log should contain more info. What does it say?

Comment: Take a look at this microsoft support page : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839174

Comment: Will try to get an event log. Sorry looked at the above link and it was not much help.

Comment: Similar error and resolved : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356360/windows-service-error-1053

see if this can help you, also the account under which the service runs should have appropriate permissions to assess the files, check that too.

Comment: Sorry to feign ignorance. Put could i get direction on how to set up an event log for this error. Plus i installed the service running the developer command prompt as administrator plus the service is set as local system. Is that good enough for permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuilt my whole solution. It appeared this project from code project had issues or would not run for me. So i basically got a windows service from Microsoft to work :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx. Then i used what worked in the file watcher console application previously mentioned and now works. I also created a ftp class. I am now investigating why creating a file fires three events: create, then delete and create again. I have not show shown the app.config file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DirectoryWatcher
{
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    static void Main()
    {
        #if(!DEBUG)
            ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { 
                new Service1() 
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        #else
            Service1 MyServ = new Service1();
            MyServ.OnDebug();
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
        #endif
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DirectoryWatcher
{
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(
                "MySource", "MyNewLog");
        }
        eventLog1.Source = "MySource";
        eventLog1.Log = "MyNewLog";
    }

    private static string fileName = "",filePath= "";

    private static string[] pathArr;

    static ftpClass1 ftpDavid = new      ftpClass1(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpServer"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"]);
    //ftpClass ftpDavid = new ftpClass();



    public void OnDebug()
    {
        OnStart(null);
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();//
        //StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt");
        watcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["watcherPath"];
        /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and
           the renaming of files or directories. */
        //watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
        // Only watch text files.
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        //ftpClass1 ftpDavid = new ftpClass1(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpServer"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"]);
        // Add event handlers.
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Created);
        watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(FileWatcher_Deleted);
        watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(FileWatcher_Renamed);

        // Begin watching.
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;


    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In onStop.");
    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnContinue.");
    }

    private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.

        /*
        Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);

        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("c:\\logdir\\logFileWatcherConsole.txt", true))
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File : "+e.FullPath+" Changed");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        */

    }

    private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
        Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("c:\\logdir\\logFileWatcherConsole.txt", true))
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }

    private static void FileWatcher_Created(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //code here for newly created file or directory
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"], true))
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File : " + e.FullPath + " created");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        pathArr = e.FullPath.Split('\\');
        fileName = pathArr[pathArr.Length -1];
        filePath = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length -1;i++ )
        {
            filePath = filePath +  pathArr[i] +"\\";
        }
        //Ftp(fileName);
        //ftpClass1 ftp1 = new ftpClass1(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpServer"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"]);
        ftpDavid.upload(fileName,filePath + fileName);


    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Event occurs when the a File or Directory is deleted
    /// </summary>
    private static void FileWatcher_Deleted(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        //code here for newly deleted file or directory
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"], true))
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File : " + e.FullPath + " deleted");
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        pathArr = e.FullPath.Split('\\');
        fileName = pathArr[pathArr.Length - 1];
        filePath = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            filePath = filePath + pathArr[i] + "\\";
        }
        //Ftp(fileName);
        //ftpClass1 ftp2 = new ftpClass1(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpServer"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"]);
        ftpDavid.delete(fileName);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Event occurs when the a File or Directory is renamed
    /// </summary>
    private static void FileWatcher_Renamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        //code here for newly renamed file or directory
        using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["logFile"], true))
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File : " + e.OldFullPath + " renamed to "+ e.FullPath);
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
        }
        pathArr = e.OldFullPath.Split('\\');
        fileName = pathArr[pathArr.Length - 1];
        pathArr = e.FullPath.Split('\\');
        filePath = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < pathArr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            filePath = filePath + pathArr[i] + "\\";
        }
        //Ftp(fileName);
        ftpDavid.rename(fileName, pathArr[pathArr.Length - 1]);

    }

    private static void Ftp(string FileName)
    {
        try
        {

            // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
            FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpServer"] + FileName);
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

            // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ftpPassword"]);

            // Copy the contents of the file to the request stream.
            //fileInfo = new FileInfo(FileName);
            StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(filePath +FileName);
            byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
            sourceStream.Close();
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter("c:\\logdir\\logFileWatcherConsole.txt", true))
            {
                w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
                w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                w.WriteLine("  :");
                w.WriteLine("  :{0}", "File : " + FileName + " uploaded");
                w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            }

            response.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static FileInfo fileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace DirectoryWatcher
 {
 class ftpClass1
 {
        private string host = null;
        private string user = null;
        private string pass = null;
        private FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = null;
        private FtpWebResponse ftpResponse = null;
        private Stream ftpStream = null;
        private int bufferSize = 2048;

        /* Construct Object */
        public ftpClass1(string hostIP, string userName, string password) { host = hostIP; user = userName; pass = password; }

        /* Download File */
        public void download(string remoteFile, string localFile)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                /* Open a File Stream to Write the Downloaded File */
                FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
                /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                /* Download the File by Writing the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
                try
                {
                    while (bytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        localFileStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        bytesRead = ftpStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                localFileStream.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }

        /* Upload File */
        public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + remoteFile);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();
                /* Open a File Stream to Read the File for Upload */
                FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Create);
                /* Buffer for the Downloaded Data */
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                /* Upload the File by Sending the Buffered Data Until the Transfer is Complete */
                try
                {
                    while (bytesSent != 0)
                    {
                        ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                        bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                localFileStream.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }

        /* Delete File */
        public void delete(string deleteFile)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host +  deleteFile);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }

        /* Rename File */
        public void rename(string currentFileNameAndPath, string newFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host +  currentFileNameAndPath);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.Rename;
                /* Rename the File */
                ftpRequest.RenameTo = newFileName;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }

        /* Create a New Directory on the FTP Server */
        public void createDirectory(string newDirectory)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(host + "/" + newDirectory);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            return;
        }

        /* Get the Date/Time a File was Created */
        public string getFileCreatedDateTime(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + fileName);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
                StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
                /* Store the Raw Response */
                string fileInfo = null;
                /* Read the Full Response Stream */
                try { fileInfo = ftpReader.ReadToEnd(); }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpReader.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
                /* Return File Created Date Time */
                return fileInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
            return "";
        }

        /* Get the Size of a File */
        public string getFileSize(string fileName)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + fileName);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetFileSize;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
                StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
                /* Store the Raw Response */
                string fileInfo = null;
                /* Read the Full Response Stream */
                try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { fileInfo = ftpReader.ReadToEnd(); } }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpReader.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
                /* Return File Size */
                return fileInfo;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
            return "";
        }

        /* List Directory Contents File/Folder Name Only */
        public string[] directoryListSimple(string directory)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
                StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
                /* Store the Raw Response */
                string directoryRaw = null;
                /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
                try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpReader.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
                /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
                try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
            return new string[] { "" };
        }

        /* List Directory Contents in Detail (Name, Size, Created, etc.) */
        public string[] directoryListDetailed(string directory)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Create an FTP Request */
                ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + directory);
                /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
                ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
                /* When in doubt, use these options */
                ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
                ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
                ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
                /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
                ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
                /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
                ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();
                /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
                StreamReader ftpReader = new StreamReader(ftpStream);
                /* Store the Raw Response */
                string directoryRaw = null;
                /* Read Each Line of the Response and Append a Pipe to Each Line for Easy Parsing */
                try { while (ftpReader.Peek() != -1) { directoryRaw += ftpReader.ReadLine() + "|"; } }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
                /* Resource Cleanup */
                ftpReader.Close();
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpResponse.Close();
                ftpRequest = null;
                /* Return the Directory Listing as a string Array by Parsing 'directoryRaw' with the Delimiter you Append (I use | in This Example) */
                try { string[] directoryList = directoryRaw.Split("|".ToCharArray()); return directoryList; }
                catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
            /* Return an Empty string Array if an Exception Occurs */
            return new string[] { "" };
        }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss Mybase.OnStart(args), you are using override.

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{

```
 MyBase.OnStart(args);

 FileWatcher.Path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WatchPath"];
 //StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt");
```

}

Comment: MyBase ? what are you referring to here?